Hausdorff measure on $\mathbb{R^n}$
I'm trying to do this question, but I fail to see the next step: 
If $A=[0,1]^n$, then prove that there exists a constant $C_n$ such that:
$$ \mathcal H _\delta^\epsilon(A) \leq C_n \epsilon^{\delta -n} $$
I can write:
$$ \mathcal H_\delta^\epsilon (A) = inf_{(B_k)_k \in R_\epsilon (A)} (\sum(diam B_k)^n (diam B_k)^{\delta-n}) $$ 
(Where $R_\epsilon (A)$ is the set of balls sequences with diameters less than $\epsilon$ and cover $A$.) 
And then because  $\epsilon$ is bigger than all diameters, and $\epsilon \mapsto \mathcal H_\delta^\epsilon (A)$ is a decreasing function:
$$ \mathcal H_\delta^\epsilon (A) \leq \mathcal H_n^\epsilon (A) \epsilon^{\delta-n} \leq \mathcal H_n(A)\epsilon^{\delta-n} $$

But I fail to see how $\mathcal H_n(A)$ can not be infinite to say that it is a constant.

And then when $n \lt \delta$, by passing to the limit of $\epsilon$ to $0$, I get $\mathcal H_\delta(A)=0$.

And my second question is how can I show that $\mathcal H_\delta(\mathbb{R}^n)=0$ if $n \lt \delta$?


I’m sorry but your question ‘1.’ is not so clear - can you try to rephrase it as a direct question?

@SBK yes, the question is how can I prove that $\mathcal H_n (A)$ is a constant?
Because initially we are asked to bound $\mathcal H_\delta^\epsilon (A)$ by something like $C \epsilon^{\delta-n}$ where $C$ is a constant.

Two things I notice: 1. I don’t think you should use balls to define Hausdorff measure. The sets in the coverings should usually be arbitrary. And 2. I think maybe you just need to set $\delta = n$? If I understand the first bit, it is for general $\delta$?

@SBK, The question uses open balls to definie Hausdorff measure. And yes it is for a general $\delta$, if $n=\delta$ we won't be able to say that the measure of $A$ is zero when we pass to the limit.

A does not have n dimensional measure equal to zero. I think I just don’t understand what you’re doing. As I said, I would try to rewrite the question

@SBD Well, what I want is to prove that $A$ has a finite n-dimensional measure, so that if $\delta \gt n$, $A$ has $\delta$ dimensional measure equal to zero.
I found this post that proves it:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246541/show-that-the-n-dimensional-hausdorff-measure-of-an-n-dimensional-cube-is-posi
So the problem now, is how to say that $\mathbb{R}^n$ has $\delta$ dimensional measure equal to zero.
